# DataContractSerializer not Serializing member of class that inherits ISerializable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Grouping
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Group<T> : HashSet<T>
    {
        public Group(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        protected Group(){}

        protected Group(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context):base(info,context)
        {
            name = info.GetString("koosnaampje");
        }

        public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
        {
            base.GetObjectData(info,context);
            info.AddValue("koosnaampje", Name);
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            private set { name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

As it inherits from HashSet it has to implement ISerializable, hence the protected constructor and GetObjectData method.
Formerly I serialized and deserialized this class succesfully with the BinaryFormatter.

Because I want to be able to inspect the output that is generated by the serializer I want to switch to the DataContractSerializer.

I wrote this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SerializeTest()
{
    var group = new Group<int>("ints"){1,2,3};
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Group<int>));
    using (var stream=File.OpenWrite("group1.xml"))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream,group);
    }
    using (var stream=File.OpenRead("group1.xml"))
    {
        group = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Group<int>;
    }
    Assert.IsTrue(group.Contains(1));
    Assert.AreEqual("ints",group.Name);
}
```

The test fails because the Name property is null! (the integers are (de)serialized correctly though)
What is happening?

EDIT:  it has nothing to do with the name backing field being private. Making it public has the same result.

Comment: Why would the data contract serializer serialize that? There's no `[DataContract]` or `[DataMember]` attributes.

Comment: @John: I tried that of course. But I got an exception stating that: Type 'Grouping.Group`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' cannot be ISerializable and have DataContractAttribute attribute.. I thought that the DataContractSerializer would be perfectly happy with classes that are marked with the SerializableAttribute.

Comment: @John - DCS does do that now... it used to be pure "I demand a contract", but now it will also infer one if missing. A corruption, IMO. It works like BinaryFormatter - i.e. it looks at the **fields**; which is quite easily the worst possible way it could have been done. But I'm not bitter.

Comment: @Marc: an abomination. Almost as bad as Web Site Projects.

Comment: See also: [XMLSerialize a custom collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377486/xmlserialize-a-custom-collection "XMLSerialize a custom collection")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing to do with `ISerializable`; `DataContractSerializer` simply doesn't **use** `ISerializable` (it will use `IXmlSerializable`, but you don't want to do that...)

Most serializers, including `XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer` (and data-binding, for that matter), treat collections as different to entities. It can be one **or** the other, but not both. Because it detects that it is a "collection", it serializes the **contents** (i.e. whatever is in the set), not the properties (`Name` etc).

You should *encapsulate* a collection, rather than *inherit* it.

Also; to correctly use `DataContractSerializer`, it would be wise to add the `[DataMember]`/`[DataContract]` attributes. For example:

```
[Serializable, DataContract] // probably don't need [Serializable]
public class Group<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public HashSet<T> Items { get; private set; }

    protected Group()
    {
        Items = new HashSet<T>();
    }
    public Group(string name) : this()
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get ;private set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the contents of the inherited collection were indeed correctly serialized, but not the members of the inheriting class. I will adjust the code to show that.