# When a class is inherited from List<>, XmlSerializer doesn't serialize other attributes

Tags: c#, .net, list, xml-serialization, ienumerable

I'm having a situation here, I need my class to be inherited from `List<ItemType>`, but when I do this XmlSerializer does not serialize any property or field declared in my class, the following sample demonstrates:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoSerialize();
    }
    private void DoSerialize()
    {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.Add(1);
        obj.Add(2);
        obj.Add(3);
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        s.Serialize(sw, obj);
    }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class MyClass : List<int>
{
    public MyClass()
    {
    }
    int myAttribute = 2011;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int MyAttribute
    {
        get
        {
            return myAttribute;
        }
        set
        {
            myAttribute = value;
        }
    }
}
```

the resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <int>1</int>
  <int>2</int>
  <int>3</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

Comment: This is one of many reasons you generally shouldn't subclass `List`.

Comment: @kirk: Yeah, I think also the same, but this time I have to, I didn't start the project, it's like this and I have to do serialization on it

Comment: @Kirk not disagreeing with that principle, but here (per the link in @driis answer) the problem is actually that implementing `IEnumerable` *at all* means your own properties don't get serialised! Which seems pretty harsh...

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlSerializer doesn't serialize everything in my class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797947/xmlserializer-doesnt-serialize-everything-in-my-class)

Comment: @AakashM Sorry for the duplicate, I searched but didn't find it, perhaps I was using the wrong kewords

Comment: @AakashM -- it's bitten me too in the past.  But really, what business do entities have implementing `IEnumerable` *or* `IList`?

Comment: Also, for posterity, `[Serializable]` is ignored by the XML Serializer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is by design. I don't know why this decision was made, [but it is stated in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx):

> - Classes that implement ICollection or IEnumerable. Only collections are
>     serialized, not public properties.

(Look under "Items that can be serialized" section). [Someone has filed a bug against this, but it won't be changed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105767/xmlserializer-cant-serialize-properties-of-type-ilist-t) - here, Microsoft also confirms that not including the properties for classes implementing `ICollection` is in fact the behaviour of XmlSerializer.

A workaround would be to either:

- Implement `IXmlSerializable` and control serialization yourself.

*or*

- Change MyClass so it has a public property of type List (and don't subclass it).

*or*

- Use DataContractSerializer, which handles this scenario.

Comment: I thought that would be the answer but I was just wanted to make sure, I asked cuz I couldn't find it in the documentation, Thank you

Comment: Hi, found this question here like 5 years later.
Since this is still a problem - how would you do that with DataContractSerializer?

Comment: Have you tried to solve it with `DataContractSerializer`. Can't get it working (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301839/serializing-class-inherited-from-list-using-datacontractserializer-does-not-se)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a though for you to consider.

You can have a class that is a container class like this:

```
class ContainerObject
{
     public int MyNewProperty { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("")]
     public List<int> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

The trick is to have XmlElement name  = "" above the List element.

When this is serialized into xml, you will have:

```
<ContainerObject>
   <MyNewProperty>...</MyNewProperty>

   <int>...</int>
   <int>...</int>

</ContainerObject>
```

If you like, you can also create another class for items in a list

```
 class MyItem
 {
     public int MyProperty {get;set;} 

 }
```

and then instead of having List of ints, have a List of MyItems.

This was you control XmlElement name of every item in a list.

I hope this was helpful.