# DataContractSerializer ignores fields in subclass of Collections

Tags: c#, serialization, collections, subclass, datacontractserializer

I've been trying to serialize a class (see below) which inherits from `List<int>` and has fields that provide extra information.

Originally, I had been using `XmlSerializer`, however I was having issues there as well.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069099/when-a-class-is-inherited-from-list-xmlserializer-doesnt-serialize-other-att) it is by design with `XmlSerializer` does not serialize fields but `DataContractSerializer` should work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class Group : List<int>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    Group test = new Group { Key = "Test key" };
    test.Add(60);

    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Group));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    serializer.WriteObject(stream, test);

    stream.Position = 0;
    test = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Group;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", test.Key ?? "No luck", test[0]);
}
```

Thanks,
Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. When deriving from a collection only base class will be serialized :) I would suggest creating a base wrapper class.

```
[DataContract]
class SuperWrapper {
    private List<int> _myList;
    private string _name;

    [DataMember]
    public List<int> Items { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; } }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to expose the object in this way. I think I'll have to implement a wrapper to provide the interface I needed, then part of serialization will have to be to turn the object into something like you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DTO which will contain all objects or properties

```
[DataContract]
class ResponseDTO 
{

    [DataMember]
    public List<int> ListData{ get ;set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Key{  get ;set; }
}
```