# How can I serialize a property in an inherited ICollection<T> class?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, json-serialization

I have a class that presented like

```
public class ItemCollection<T> : ICollection<T> {
    public ItemCollection() {
        Items = new List<T>();
    }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now it will be serialized into:

```json
{
    "Property": [{...}]
}
```

But I want the result is like:

```json
{
    "Property": {"Items": [{...}]}
}
```

Sorry for the missing information of this question.

I now stuck in serialization when using System.Text.Json.

In Newtonsoft.Json, I use `[JsonObject]` to annotate this class so it can serialization correctly into json with `"Items": value`, but I don't know how to serialize the `Items` property using System.Text.Json.

I have some classes inherited this class and the inheritances will be as properties in other classes.

**Solution:**

Thank you for every one that answered this question, I have found a solution to solve this. I create a `ConverterFactory` to resolve the needed types to create the converters. In the converter, I create new `JsonObject` and use `Reflection` to create the properties in the type, after this, I serialize the `JsonObject` so I can get the correct result.

Comment: When you call `JsonSerializer.Serialize` then it will call the `GetEnumerator` method of the `ItemCollection` that's why there is no `Items` there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in attribute corresponding to Newtonsoft's [`JsonObjectAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOverrideIEnumerable.htm) that will force a collection to be serialized as a JSON object.<sup>1</sup>.  And [there is no public equivalent to `IContractResolver`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182) that can be overridden to customize serialization metadata.  Thus you will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182) to serialize the properties of your `ItemCollection<T>`, such as the following:

```
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(ItemCollectionJsonConverter))]
public partial class ItemCollection<T> : ICollection<T> {
    internal ItemCollection(List<T> items) { // I added this for use by the converter
        Items = items ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    public ItemCollection() {
        Items = new List<T>();
    }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    // Remainder omitted
}

public class ItemCollectionJsonConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => GetItemCollectionValueType(typeToConvert) != null;

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ItemCollectionJsonConverterInner<>).MakeGenericType(GetItemCollectionValueType(type)!))!;

    static Type? GetItemCollectionValueType(Type type) =>
        (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ItemCollection<>)) ? type.GetGenericArguments()[0] : null;

    class ItemCollectionJsonConverterInner<T> : JsonConverter<ItemCollection<T>>
    {
        class ItemCollectionDTO
        {
            public List<T>? Items { get; set; }
            // Add other properties here
        }
    
        public override ItemCollection<T> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            // TODO: Decide whether to throw on null
            new ItemCollection<T>((JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ItemCollectionDTO>(ref reader, options)?.Items) ?? throw new JsonException());
        
        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ItemCollection<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, new ItemCollectionDTO { Items = value.Items }, options);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I added the converter directly to `ItemCollection<T>` via attributes, but you could add it to [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters) if you prefer.
- Many serializers will not serialize collection properties.  See e.g. *[XmlSerializer doesn't serialize everything in my class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1797947/3744182)* for another.
- Adding properties to collections isn't really a recommended practice; see *[Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/3744182)* for a discussion why.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5dogoY).

---

<sup>1</sup> The list of all System.Text.Json serialization attributes is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonattribute).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, but I did not found any difference between the serialization of Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json.

Perhabs you can provide an example in code to show us the problem directly.
With your provided information I got with following code example the same results

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ItemCollection<Person> list = new ItemCollection<Person> {new Person(){ FirstName = "FirstName", Name = "Name"}};
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);


        string jsonString2 =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[{"Name":"Name","FirstName":"FirstName"}]

Comment: Based on the provided sample json it seems like the OP is serializing a wrapper class, not an `ItemCollection` instance directly. Something like this: `class Wrapper { public ItemCollection Property { get; set; } }`