# How to serialize a collection that inherit from List<T> by using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I have a generic type that inherit from List,
and I want to serialize the extra properties by using System.Text.Json.
My code was just like this:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
void Main()
{
    var bars = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(i => new Bar { Id = i });
    Foo<Bar> foo = new Foo<Bar>(123, bars);
    var jsonOption = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true
    };
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo, jsonOption);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

class Foo<T> : List<T>
{
    public int Mark { get; set; }//This property can not be seriliazed!!

    public Foo(int mark, IEnumerable<T> foos)
    {
        Mark = mark;
        AddRange(foos);
    }
}
class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
//Output:
//
//[
//  {
//    "Id": 1
//  },
//  {
//  "Id": 2
//  },
//  {
//  "Id": 3
//  },
//  {
//  "Id": 4
//  }
//]
```

Sadly the preceding code does not serialize the 'Mark' property which I expected...

Comment: and how it shoud be serialized? list is serialized as json array - so additional property doesn't make sens

Comment: also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: Should you not rather create the `Foo` class without inheriting from the `List<T>` class.  The two properties will then be serialized (and also deserialized if necessary) as normal.

Comment: @Selvin
Thanks Selvin ,that's a great help. I'll modify my design.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [How can I serialize a property in an inherited ICollection<T> class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71688136/3744182) I think, but that has no upvoted or accepted answers.