# XMLserializer does not store all properties of an object in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, xmlserializer

Basically there is DrinkCategories holding an observableCollection of DrinkCategory. This nested ObservableCollection is used to provide data for a LongListSelector in WP8.

```
this.DrinkCategories = new ObservableCollection<DrinkCategory>();
```

DrinkCategory itself implements ObservableCollection and adds a "Name" property.

```
public class DrinkCategory : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DrinkViewModel>
{
    public string Name { get;  set; }

    public void AddDrink(DrinkViewModel drinkItem)
    {
        this.Items.Add(drinkItem);
    }
}
```

My XMLserializer stores the "Items" in DrinkCategory but not the "Name".

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("AvailableDrinks.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<DrinkCategory>));
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, DrinkCategories);
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ArrayOfArrayOfDrinkViewModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ArrayOfDrinkViewModel>
    <DrinkViewModel>
      Properties of DVM
    </DrinkViewModel>
    <DrinkViewModel>
      Properties of DVM
    </DrinkViewModel>
    <DrinkViewModel>
      Properties of DVM
    </DrinkViewModel>
   </ArrayOfDrinkViewModel>
   <ArrayOfDrinkViewModel>
    <DrinkViewModel>
      Properties of DVM
    </DrinkViewModel>
    <DrinkViewModel>
      Properties of DVM
    </DrinkViewModel>
    <DrinkViewModel>
      Properties of DVM
    </DrinkViewModel>
   </ArrayOfDrinkViewModel>
</ArrayOfArrayOfDrinkViewModel>
```

Where is my mistake?

EDIT: The problem seems to raise from the implementation of the "DrinkCategory"-class since a single serialized object of "DrinkCategory" holds its drinks, but not its name. `XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DrinkCategory));`

Comment: Seems as if this is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286302/why-cant-i-add-attributes-when-serializing-observablecollectiont#