# Collection attributes are not serialized to xml

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a custom serializable generic collection, defined (a simplified example) like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ArrayOfItems<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute("Setting")]
    public bool Setting { get; set; } = false;

    [XmlAnyElement]
    public List<T> Items { get; set; } = new List<T>();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        IEnumerator iterator = ((IEnumerable<T>)this).GetEnumerator();
        while ( iterator.MoveNext() )
        {
            yield return iterator.Current;
        }
    }

    public void Add( T Object )
    {
        Items.Add(Object );
    }
}
```

I create an instance and serialize it using xml serializer:

```
ArrayOfItems<int> ints = new();
ints.Items.Add(0);
ints.Items.Add(1);

using (StreamWriter writer = new 
StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml", false, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new(ints.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(writer, ints);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

And here is the file I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <int>0</int>
    <int>1</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

Does anyone understand why the bool Setting property is not serialized?

Comment: This restriction is explicitly documented by MSFT in [Serializing a class that implements the ICollection interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization#serializing-a-class-that-implements-the-icollection-interface): *When a class implements the ICollection interface, only the collection contained by the class is serialized. Any public properties or fields added to the class won't be serialized.*  (While the doc only mentions `ICollection`, it applies to `IEnumerable` also.)

Comment: See e.g. [XmlSerialize a custom collection with an Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377486) for an identical question where the answers have several workarounds such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542754) by Trevor Daniels which uses a wrapper class to generate the required XML, and looks to be a duplicate.

Comment: See also [Xml Serialization of a Collection with Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5323392) and [When a class is inherited from List<>, XmlSerializer doesn't serialize other attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5069099) (and also [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193).