# How to get an XmlAttribute from an XmlArray?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML string like this:

```
<foo>
  ...
  <barlist id="10">
    <bar ... />
    <bar ... />
    etc..
  </barlist>
</foo>
```

How do I get the `id` of `barlist` in deserializing it to an object?

My current code for doing this without serializing/deserializing the ID is this:

```
class FooData{
  [XmlArray("barlist")]
  [XmlArrayItem("bar",typeof(BarData))]
  public List<BarData> Bars;
}
```

Comment: Can't be done. XML Serialization treats collections as pure collections - it ignores attributes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlSerialize a custom collection with an Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377486/xmlserialize-a-custom-collection-with-an-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

Try add [XmlAtribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8db82dk.aspx) to id object.

**UPDATE**: I'am adding example how you can deserialize it...

Classes:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType=true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public class foo {
    [XmlElement("barlist")]
    public List<fooBarlist> barlist { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType=true)]
public class fooBarlist {
    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public List<fooBarlistBar> bar { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public byte id { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType=true)]
public class fooBarlistBar {
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public byte number { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute()]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

test xml:

```
<foo>
 <barlist id="1">
  <bar number="1" value="Hi" />
  <bar number="2" value="Hello" />
  </barlist>
  <barlist id="2">
  <bar number="3" value="Bye" />
  <bar number="4" value="Bye bye" />
  </barlist>
</foo>
```

and the code to deserialize xml to object:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(foo));
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("D:\\test.xml");
foo testObj = serialier.Deserialize(reader) as foo;
```

and then we have result

[image: result]

Comment: -1: no, that wouldn't work, even if it were spelled correctly.

Comment: @John Saunders: I updated my answer and added test example - it works for me.

Comment: Why do you have `Attribute` at the end of all the names? You know you can leave that off right?

Comment: so, your point is, if he want to change his classes, then he can do it?

Comment: I just tryed to show how it can be done thats it. I may be wrong,  my answer can be useless to user, but its suggestion.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I hadnt even considered the possibility of not using and XmlArray attribute