# XMLAttribute not taken into account

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to serialize an object with an attribute on the root element (which is a collection).

```
[XmlType("Person")]
public class Person
{
    public id Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Persons")]
public class Persons : Collection<Person>
{
    [XmlAttribute("Nb")]
    public int Nb
        get {
            return this.Count;
        }
        set { }
    }
}

var persons = new Persons();
var person = new Person();
person.Id = 42;
person.Name = "Toto";
persons.Add(person);

return persons;
```

The serialized output is the following:

```
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <Id>42</Id>
        <Name>Toto</Name>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

I'm expecting

```
<Persons Nb="1">
    <Person>
        <Id>42</Id>
        <Name>Toto</Name>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

**How can I bring the `Nb` attribute in ?**

Comment: Which serializer your are using?

Comment: My serializer is (I believe) the default one for .net core configured in `Startup` with `.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`

Comment: `class Persons : List<Person>` - [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/1997232).

Comment: Still nobody have an idea how to add my `Nb` attribute ?

Comment: ok, than I'll remove comments

Comment: Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377486/xmlserialize-a-custom-collection-with-an-attribute) seems that is similar to your case

Comment: Check this in your investigations: `[XmlRoot("Persons")]
    public class Persons : Collection<Person>, IXmlSerializable
    {
        public int Nb => Count;
        public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Nb", Nb.ToString());
            var personSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Person));
            foreach (var person in this)
            {
                personSerializer.Serialize(writer, person);
            }
        }
     }`

Comment: Your last link fixed my issue. It's due to the fact that my root class extends a collection.